# Is that grammatically right if I use two predicates without using a conjunction to link them?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Is it grammatically right if I use two predicates without using a conjunction to link them? There are many sentences using this structure when I read a composition.

Examples:

> - He became a teacher, established his own family twenty years later.
> - I saw nothing decent in him, saw nothing more than a selfish man.

Usage of conjunction: http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conjunctions.htm

Comment: Your translator's phrase is grammatical; yours is not. Please explain what research led you to your conclusion.

Comment: Do you use **i** in your translation? Just a heads-up. You received 3 close-votes and if you don't edit your question with your research/reference, your question will be closed with 2 more votes. I believe you visited our help center but you don't seem to understand the rules here. A request for proof-reading or a question without any research is **off-topic**.

Comment: <<He became a teacher; established his own family twenty years later.>> is an example of subject deletion, which is often considered acceptable in non-formal registers. <<He became a teacher. Established his own family twenty years later.>> uses a sentence fragment to give a terse style, but this again would be avoided in formal registers.  With the comma, there is a comma splice, and in these cases the sentences would more often be considered non-standard.